# Change "option + w" from typing ∑ to tying ω

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

Whenever I press option w, I get ∑. This is default behavior on macOS. How can I modify it such that instead of ∑ I get ω? I tried Karabiner Elements but it can't do greek letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) can do this kind of remapping.